# Remove mainPanel area in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to remove a mainPanel from a Shiny app? I mean, if I want a big sidePanel (without any mainPanel area), how should I do it? I have tried simply to write:

```
mainPanel()
```

but it doens't work (it just empties the area...).

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is a lot of possibilities with shiny (and even more if you know some HTML basics), I suggest you to look the code of some Shiny applications, maybe you can find something close to what you want. http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/showcase/

Comment: thank you! I did it using a wellPanel :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to imagine why you would want this :) Can you tell us how you plan to use the app? Some options:

1. You could use basicPage instead of pageWithSidebar in ui.R
2. There are also some (relatively) new layout features in Shiny discussed [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/wiki/Shiny-Application-Layout-Guide). You would need to use Shiny 0.8.0.99:

   install.packages('devtools'); library(devtools); install_github('shiny','rstudio')

Answer (score 3):

If you want something that looks like `sidePanel` but fills up the entire area, that's called `wellPanel`. Use `basicPage(wellPanel(...))` instead of `pageWithSidebar`. If you want a title, you can do `basicPage(tags$h1("My app"), wellPanel(...))`.

Comment: thank you! I did it using a wellPanel, but I've maintained the pageWithSidebar :)